# Can I log to App Insights from Powershell (maybe via log4net)?

Tags: powershell, log4net, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to log to Application Insights from Powershell?

I have the log4net logging set up in Powershell already, and that is working.  I also have demonstrated logging to Application Insights from a simple .Net console app using the log4net appender.

Is it a matter of grabbing the App Insights assemblies and placing them somewhere local to the Powershell script?  I'm just not sure what to try next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible, the same way as you call any .NET assembly / c# code from powershell.  All you need is the "core" app insights assembly/assemblies from the [core nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/), and then use `TelemetryClient.TrackEvent` etc as normal.

Comment: We weren't able to get the log4net appender working with App Insights, but we got the telemetryclient to work fine.